# Convert string into func

Tags: c#, linq

I have simple lambda as a string:

```
var str = "f => f.Substring(0, f.IndexOf(' '))";
```

which eventualy takes first word from the passed string.

What is the easiest way to compile/convert this peace of string into Func and make the following code to work.

```
Func<string, string> func = ...
var firstWord = func("Hello World");
```

Will Expression help me? Will appreciate working sample,

Thanks

Comment: So, you want `eval()` in C#...

Comment: "which eventualy takes first word from the passed string" - No it doesn't. It takes all the text up to the first space character. If the first character is a space, you'll get an empty string. If there's a word, a carriage return, another word, then a space, you'll get the first two words.

Comment: Have you tried ExpressionTree instead of strings?

Comment: @MarkByers and if there's no space character, you'll get an exception (if I recall correctly).

Comment: @phoog - you're right. [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwb0bwyd.aspx) will give -1 if no instances found, and according to [the docs for SubString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx) you'll get an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` if length (the second param) is less than 0. You could also get a `ArgumentNullException` from `IndexOf` if `f` is null.

Comment: Investigate the [Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/roslyn) project.   This will allow you to use the C# compiler through an API.  I don't know whether it will handle bare expressions like that.

Comment: Can you provide more info on why you want to do this? Why are you limited to expressing the lambda as a string?

Comment: Just a comment on this. Though there are ways to do this, they will tend to run slowly. However if you find a version that does convert a string to a func, then store the func object in memory rather than interpret the string mulitple times.  Something likes this if it is a web application, however the eval function is ficticious:
Application["Func1"] = eval("f => f.Substring(0, f.IndexOf(' '))");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to examine the string and construct an expression from the provided string. There is no *easy* or *built in method* to obtain a method from a string like this.

Good luck.

Answer (score 11):

Problem is that there is no strong typing support here, so you can't even utilize expression trees. However, [DynamicLinq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio//bb894665.aspx) already does this, so you can easily get this working with a few modifications. Just create a few static methods of your own in the DynamicExpression class to add this functionality:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, S>> ParseLambda<T, S>(string expression)
{
    string paramString = expression.Substring(0, expression.IndexOf("=>")).Trim();
    string lambdaString = expression.Substring(expression.IndexOf("=>") + 2).Trim();
    ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), paramString);
    return (Expression<Func<T,S>>)ParseLambda(new[] { param }, typeof(S), lambdaString, null);
}

public static LambdaExpression ParseLambda(string expression, Type returnType, params Type[] paramTypes)
{
    string paramString = expression.Substring(0, expression.IndexOf("=>")).Trim("() ".ToCharArray());
    string lambdaString = expression.Substring(expression.IndexOf("=>") + 2).Trim();
    var paramList = paramString.Split(',');
    if (paramList.Length != paramTypes.Length)
        throw new ArgumentException("Specified number of lambda parameters do not match the number of parameter types!", "expression");

    List<ParameterExpression> parameters = new List<ParameterExpression>();
    for (int i = 0; i < paramList.Length; i++)
        parameters.Add(Expression.Parameter(paramTypes[i], paramList[i].Trim()));

    return ParseLambda(parameters.ToArray(), returnType, lambdaString, null);
}
```

Usage for both:

```
Func<string, string> func = DynamicExpression.ParseLambda<string, string>("f => f.Substring(0, f.IndexOf(\" \"))").Compile();

Func<string, int, string> otherFunc = ((Expression<Func<string, int, string>>)DynamicExpression.ParseLambda("(str, ind) => (ind * 100).ToString() + str")).Compile();
```

Edit: This has not been thoroughly tested, so you might want to make sure with some unit tests that these produce the correct results. I'm not doing anything overly complicated, just explicitly declaring the parameters to use in the `public static LambdaExpression ParseLambda(ParameterExpression[] parameters, Type resultType, string expression, params object[] values)` method.
Also fixed bug pointed out by @Mauro Destro by trimming the parameter name from `paramList` when creating the `ParameterExpression`.

Comment: This solution works! But must be changed the parameter parser because it fail with spaces after comma

Answer (score 6):

You can use Roslyn scripting to do this. For example:

```
var str = "f => f.Substring(0, f.IndexOf(' '))";
var func = await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<Func<string, string>>(str);
var firstWord = func("Hello World");
```

This requires the `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting` package.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in CodeDom technology. [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx)

There is no ready parser there, though.